# DB: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, database-connection, pymysql

Getting a "Lost Connection" error after I try `with engine.begin() as conn`. Here's my code:

```
...
connection_pool = get_connection_pool(_db)

    conn = connection_pool.getconn()

    server = str(_db.credentials.host) + ":" + str(_db.credentials.port)
    database = _db.credentials.database
    user = _db.credentials.user
    password = _db.credentials.password
    # connection_string = "DRIVER={mysql+pymysql};" + "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database +";UID=" + user + ";PWD=" + password
    # connection_url = URL.create('mysql+pymysql', query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    connection_url = "mysql+pymysql://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + database
    try:
        q = query.as_string((conn))
        engine = create_engine(connection_url)
        _logger.info(q)
        with engine.begin() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as ex:
        _logger.info(ex)
        raise ex
    finally:
        connection_pool.putconn(conn)
...
```

Anyone know a solution to this?

I tried expanding pool timeout but no luck.

Comment: `except psycopg2.DatabaseError`? According to your code you use pymysql (dburi).

Answer (score -3):

Fixed by changing the driver to `postgresql`, what my database was using, instead of `mysql+pymysql`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).